# why "find" function in mongoose doesn't return the object from data base

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I created a mongoDB server as part of a website.
I need to search the users database when someone log in to check if their user exist.

here is the schema

```
    let schema = new mongodb.Schema({
     username: {
       type: String,
       required: true,
       unique: true,
       index: true
     },
     password: {
       type: String,
       required: true
     },
     type: Number,
     active: Boolean
   });
```

and here is the login function

```
   schema.statics.LOGIN = async function(username, password) {
     return await this.find({
       username,
       password
     });
   }
```

however when I try to log in I get a wired hierarchical of objects and my object is deep inside of this hierarchy

I took a picture of the value of the object I get from the "find" function, as it was shown in webstorm. The real value I want is inside the _doc object as you can see in the picture
[returned object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yADME.png)

note that I cant use promises ,the function LOGIN has to return a value

Comment: What you get is an array. Just fetch its first value or use `findOne` (or what is its name in mongoose)

Comment: You can't "await" there. The `statics`have a callback or a return a Promise. You `await` the call you make to the actual "static" method. i.e `let result = await Model.LOGIN()` and not `let result = Model.LOGIN()`, which is what you appear to be doing.

Comment: You have to either use a promise or a callback with find.

Comment: More to the point, get some es-lint rules: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-await. I like things like this because that stop you from making such mistakes or misconceptions.